# Web service asynchroneous call : waiting until the service treatment is finished

Tags: java, web-services, asynchronous, apache-axis

I'm writing my first asynchronous call to my web service here's the code :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  String en ="x" ;
  String ar="xxxx" ;
  String tai ="x" ;
WsStub wsStub = new WsStub("http://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
WebServiceCallbackHandler webServiceCallHandler  = new WebServiceCallbackHandler();
DemDis  demDisp;

demDis = DemDis.Factory.newInstance();
demDis.setEn(en);
demDis.setArt(ar);
demDis.setTaille(tai);
DemDisDocument  document = DemDisDocument.Factory.newInstance();
document.setDemDis(demandeDisponibilite);

for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {      
  wsStub.startdisp(document, webServiceCallHandler);
}

Thread.sleep(60000);
}
```

Here's the callback handler implementation :

```
public class WebServiceCallbackHandler extends WsCallbackHandler {


  public void receiveResultdis(fr.srd.ws.wsb.ReponseDisDocument result) {
   System.out.println(result);
}

public void receiveErrordis(java.lang.Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

It works fine but i want to add this :

The thread should wait until the service responds to all clients request(The service's treatment is finished).

Comment: And how do you know in the server how many clients you have?

Comment: here's the number of clients for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)

Comment: Yes, this is clear, but this 500 is known at the client, but the server (or callback) doesn't know when you are finished sending requests.